# Dijkstra's alghoritm with OpenMP

Tags: c++, openmp

There is a fully working Dijkstra algorithm that takes values ​​from a file (or writes a new one) and writes data to a matrix. How can you improve the program using OpenMP so that its speed is significantly increased? New to openMP, had little experience with common matrices, mostly parallelization "for".

I attach all the code below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <climits>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <iomanip>
#include <locale.h>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;

class Timer
{
private:
    using clock_t = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock;
    using second_t = std::chrono::duration<double, std::ratio<1> >;

    chrono::time_point<clock_t> m_beg;

public:
    Timer() : m_beg(clock_t::now())
    {
    }

    double elapsed() const
    {
        return std::chrono::duration_cast<second_t>(clock_t::now() - m_beg).count();
    }
};

void fillingArray(int** arr, int c, string filename) {
    ofstream fout(filename);
    srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(0)));
    for (int i = 0; i < c; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < c; j++) {
            arr[i][j] = arr[j][i] = rand() % 10 + 1;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < c; i++) {
        fout << endl;
        for (int j = 0; j < c; j++) {
            fout << setw(5) << arr[i][j];
        }
    }
}

void read(int** arr, int c, string filename) {
    char answer;
    ifstream file;
    file.open(filename);
    if (!file) {
        fillingArray(arr, c, filename);
    }
    else {
        cout << "File found\nWant to overwrite it? (y / n)\n";
        cin >> answer;
        if (answer == 'y' || answer == 'Y') {
            fillingArray(arr, c, filename);
        }
        else {
            for (int i = 0; i < c; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < c; j++) {
                    file >> arr[i][j];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    file.close();
}

void Dijkstra(int** arr, int c, int st)
{
    Timer t;

    int count, index, i, u, m = st + 1;
    int* distance = (int*)malloc(c * sizeof(int*));
    bool* visited = new bool[c];
    for (i = 0; i < c; i++)
    {
        distance[i] = INT_MAX; visited[i] = false;
    }
    distance[st] = 0;
    for (count = 0; count < c - 1; count++)
    {
        int min = INT_MAX;
        for (i = 0; i < c; i++)
            if (!visited[i] && distance[i] <= min)
            {
                min = distance[i]; index = i;
            }
        u = index;
        visited[u] = true;
        for (i = 0; i < c; i++)
            if (!visited[i] && arr[u][i] && distance[u] != INT_MAX &&
                distance[u] + arr[u][i] < distance[i])
                distance[i] = distance[u] + arr[u][i];
    }
    double time = t.elapsed();

    cout << "Cost of the path from the initial peak to the rest:\t\n";
    for (i = 0; i < c; i++) if (distance[i] != INT_MAX)
        cout << m << " > " << i + 1 << " = " << distance[i] << endl;
    else cout << m << " > " << i + 1 << " = " << "route not available" << endl;

    cout << "Time passed: " << time << "с\n";
    delete[] visited;
    delete[] distance;
}

int main()
{
    string filename, rash;
    filename = "arr";
    rash = ".dat";

    int c;
    cout << "Enter the number of ribs:\n";
    cin >> c;

    int** arr = (int**)malloc(c * sizeof(int*));
    for (int i = 0; i < c; i++) {
        arr[i] = (int*)malloc(c * sizeof(int));
    }

    filename += to_string(c) + rash;

    read(arr, c, filename);

    Dijkstra(arr, c, 0);

    delete[] arr;
}
```

Comment: It seems the input graph have `c` nodes and you already computed the distance of the `c`^2 possible edges (which may be filled with +inf). Your Dijkstra algorithm run in `O(c^2)` time which is not efficient (at least on weakly connected graphs). That being said, Dijkstra is rather sequential algorithm and thus very hard to parallelize (if possible). Moreover, note that parallelism will only be interesting with big graphs (so cases where your algorithm is not efficient). I advise you to improve the algorithm complexity before trying to parallelize it.

Comment: @JérômeRichard, you are right, I already have a reworked program, but it also has minor problems, this time with a violation of read access